# Почему звук после подключения клавиатуры был, но она не работает?

Tags: клавиатура, usb

Во время игры клавиатура отключилась и пропала подсветка, вытянул с usb-порта, вставил обратно, звук был, что она подключилась, но клавиатура не работает.

Захожу в ПО Dark Project, пишет подключите клавиатуру, в настройках windows она определяется как wpm usb.

Пробовал подключать в другой пк, все равно не работает, пробовал даже кабель менять на другой проблема осталась, сегодня весь интернет облазил но так и решения не нашёл, я не могу понять в чём проблема. Кто знает, в чём проблема или даже знает решение, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: видимо просто приказала долго жить и судя по отзывам у кого то эта клавиатура прям с первого запуска таким страдала и вроде как это брак

Answer (score -3):

у меня Игровая клавиатура DARK PROJECT One KD87A ABS Gateron Mechanical Red ENG/UA (DPO-KD-87A-000300-GRD) на клаве модель  DARK PROJECT One KD87A мне подошли эти дрова https://darkproject.eu/downloads/?category=30&model=917  DPO KD87 Skeleton   или попробуй DPO KD87 Skeleton V2